# Adding transition-group component on-top of custom component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom component that requires to have a `v-for` list underneath it.

```
<draggable>
   <div v-for="item in items">...</div>
</draggable>
```

I'm trying to add a `<transition-group>` component to add animations when the list items change. The issue is if I set the `<transition-group>` component as a child the `<draggable>` component the `<draggable>` doesn't work. If I set the `<transition-group>` as a parent of `<draggable>` then transition group doesn't work. What is a workout around for this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
<draggable>
  <div>
   <transition-group>
     <div v-for="item in items">...</div>
   </transition-group>
  </div>
</draggable>
```

Comment: you shouldn't really need the wrapping div for the transition-group

Comment: draggable won't work since it'll only have 1 child. When I drag something it'll drag that entire child

Comment: You need draggable for items? Then, add draggable attribute inside v-for itself.